# How do i use fs:bx in call instruction at Flat Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, fasm

I am creating a Kernel and I need some help with the call instruction. I am using Flat Assembler to build the Kernel.

```
call fs:bx
```

Is that possible ?
Because flat assembler gives me an "invalid size of operand" Error.

I know I can do

```
call 1000h:0h
```

But that is not what I want. Does someone have the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `call fs:bx` to set `cs=fs` and `ip=bx`, as a far call.

Indirect far calls require the seg:offset to be in memory, not registers.  See [the insn ref entry for `call`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) to confirm that the only available indirect `far call` is the `call m16:16` form.

So in 16-bit code, you could

```
push   fs
push   bx
...    ;  push args
far call   [bp-whatever]       ; assuming you know the difference between bp and sp at this point
add    sp, 4 + arg_size     ; clean up args and the far-pointer
```

Or reserve space on the stack ahead of time so you can do something like

```
my_function:
    push       bp
    mov        bp, sp
    sub        sp, 16          ; or whatever size you need for locals.  16 and 8 are just for example.

    ...

    mov        [bp - 8], fs
    mov        [bp - 6], bx    ; separately store both parts of fs:bx into [bp-8]
    far call   [bp - 8]

    ...
    leave
    ret
```

You can't `mov cs, fs` or anything like that (even using a scratch GP register).  Changing `cs` would be a jump, so you have to do the whole thing as one `far call`.

---

Of course, you probably only put the segment value in `fs` in the first place to set up for this instruction, so don't do that in the first place.

Comment: I have a question: what does "whatever" mean in your example?

Comment: @SeeSoftware: It's a numeric constant that depends on the size of the stack frame (i.e. the difference between bp and sp after pushing fs and bx.)  Equivalently, you could reserve some space in your function's stack ahead of time so you can `mov [bp - 8], fs` / `mov [bp - 6], bx` / ... / `call [bp - 8]`

Comment: actually you can just use [sp] instead of [bp-whatever] and it works fine for me btw how to return from it ?  "ret" or "retf" or something else  EDIT: you cant use sp directly you have to put it into another register

Comment: @SeeSoftware: yup, 16-bit code has annoying restrictions on addressing modes, see [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  And yes, you need to do a far return.  I've never written 16-bit code that does anything with far pointers, but I think far call just pushes cs:ip where a `retf` can pop it.  IDK what the FASM syntax for a far return is, but you can check with a disassembler to make sure it generated a [`0xCB` opcode](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html).  I'm not a fan of 16-bit code, and wouldn't recommend it as a way to learn asm if you don't already know x86.

Comment: how do i fix/clear the stack after the call? im not an expert in the stack and stuff but i think you just have to increment the stack pointer?

Comment: @SeeSoftware: yes, if you pushed 8 bytes of args, `add sp, 8`